# prevent a Salt state from running when condition is not met

Tags: salt-stack

I have a Salt state that I only want to be executed when the target operating system is not RedHat; if the OS is RedHat, then I'd like to return just an error message.

In order to do that, I've been adding this at the top of the .sls file:

```
{% if grains['os'] == RedHat %}
RedHat not supported
{% endif %}
```

The above works because the message I've inserted is not a valid entry and then it failed to compile when the target operating system is RedHat, but I feel this is just a hack; I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution to this problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code below RedHat servers will only run the **test.succeed_without_changes** state.

The state: **test.succeed_without_changes** will ensure you that the minion has executed this job and that it has no changes which is useful in your logging.

Only servers with another OS are executing the real states in you statefile.

Code:

```
{% if grains['os'] == RedHat %}

RedHat-server-logging-state:
  test.succeed_without_changes:
    - name: RedHat OS detected

{% else %}

Execution-state-1:
  test.succeed_with_changes:
    - name: State 1 executed on non RedHat server

Execution-state-2:
  test.succeed_with_changes:
    - name: State 2 executed on non RedHat server

{% endif %}
```

Comment: I've finally decided to use 'test.fail_without_changes' , but your suggestion pointed me to the right direction. Thanks!